# Security for a Windows refugee

Tags: security, opensuse

I recently migrated from Microsoft's Windows 7 to Gnu/Linux, on my home PC. Back in MS-Windows, there were programs that would alert me if shodan or similar networks were probing my computer and give me a choice to block or accept connections from them.

Is there something similar for Gnu/Linux, for someone on a low budget? I have installed snort, but I noticed my computer became slower. Then I tried to run Security Onion on Virtualbox. My supposedly new laptop crashed. I haven't been able to run any OS on Virtualbox without having to manually reboot my computer.

What would you guys suggest?

Comment: ... if any random website can portscan your computer, you should probably rather check how your router/firewall is configured.

Comment: Network coneections, routing, etc in Linux is controled using iptables/nftables. There are many programs that allow graphical control of FW rules, check https://www.techradar.com/best/best-free-linux-firewalls

Comment: What web-server are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux boxes usually get a local firewall configured. That should stop most miscreant's traffic dead. Check out the firewall configuration for your distribution, edit to taste. Just make *sure* you understand what you are doing (check several sites, look for comments on suggestions, see if it makes sense). It is very easy to break networking in subtle ways. Remember, Unix/Linux assumes *you* know what you are doing, no second guessing. You asked for it, you get it.